# Bott's topological obstruction to integrability

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, characteristic-classes, connections, integrable-systems

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $E\subseteq TM$ be an integrable distribution and $\pi:TM\to Q=\frac{TM}{E}$ the quotient bundle with $\dim Q=q$.
Bott showed that 
\begin{equation}
Pont^k(Q)=0 \qquad \forall k>2q \label{dd}
\end{equation}
and togehter with the proposition that $Pont(Q)=Pont(Q')$ for homotopy equivalent distributions $E$ and $E'$ it follows that the Pontryagin classes  in the above equation already vanish when $E$ is homotopy equivalent to an integrable distribution.

I don't understand one step in the argument.

One shows that there is exists a partial connection $\nabla:\Gamma(E)\times \Gamma(Q)\to\Gamma(Q)$  defined by
\begin{equation}
\nabla_X(Z)=\pi[X,\tilde Z]
\end{equation}
where  $Z=\pi(\tilde Z)$.
One can show that the corresponding 'partial ' curvature form $k$ vanishes
\begin{equation}
k(X,X')(Z)=\nabla_X\nabla_{X'}Z-\nabla_{X'}\nabla_X Z -\nabla_{[X,X']}Z=0
\end{equation}

How does this show that the Pontryagin classes vanish beyond the order $2q$?

Comment: Are you familiar with representing the Pontryagin classes by ad-invariant polynomials in the curvature $2$-form? Because $E$ is integrable, there are local coordinates $(x^1,\dots,x^n)$ on $M$ so that $E = \{dx^1=\dots=dx^q=0\}$ and this is a differentially-closed ideal. Since the connection forms of $Q$ belong to this ideal, so do the curvature forms $\Omega_Q$, and so any (invariant) polynomial of degree higher than $2q$ in $\Omega_Q$ will have to vanish.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ted for the comment. I am semi acquainted with ad-invariant polynomials, but have no hands on experience. I will look over it and make my question more specific.